# When $\frac{\xi x}{\xi -x}$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I'm working on a function $\lambda(\xi)$ that takes in input an intger $\xi$ and calculate for how many values of $x\in N$, with $0\leq x < \xi$, the ratio: $$\psi = \frac{\xi x}{\xi -x}$$ is an integer $(\psi \in N)$.

Here there is a graph of $\lambda(\xi)$ for $2\leq \xi \leq113$, created in Excel:
[image]

I have tried in a lot of diferent ways (supposing for example $\xi$ is odd and $x$ is even), but I can't faind a solution. Any idea?

Comment: This is equal to the number of positive integer divisors of $\xi^2$.

Comment: Why it's equal to the number of divisors of $\xi^2$?

Comment: Because $\psi = \frac{\xi^2}{\xi-x}-\xi\in\mathbb{N}\iff \frac{\xi^2}{\xi-x}\in\mathbb{N}$ and the latter is true only when $(\xi-x)|\xi^2$ i.e. once for each divisor of $\xi^2$.

Comment: I think it's not correct because if you put $\xi = 60$, $\xi^2$ have 45 not between 20 and 25

Comment: Sorry, we need to emit the divisors which are greater than $\xi$ so the value is equal to $\frac{d(\xi^2)+1}2$ where $d(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. For $\xi=60$ this gives $\frac{45+1}{2}=23$.

Comment: Sorry, it's difficult to understand from the graph but it starts from 2.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the assertion of Peter Foreman in its comment, that's
$$\lambda(\xi)=\frac{d(\xi^2)+1}2$$
let consider the sets
\begin{align*}
D&=\{d>0:d|\xi^2\}\\
L&=\{d\in D:d\leq\xi\}\\
U&=\{d\in D:d>\xi\}
\end{align*}
and the function
\begin{align*}
&\varphi:D\to D&&d\mapsto\xi^2/d
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align}
D&=L\cup U& L\cap U&=\varnothing\\
&\text{$\varphi$ is bijective}&\varphi[U]&=L-\{\xi\}
\end{align}
Consequently, $d(\xi^2)=|D|=|L|+|U|$ and $|U|=|L|-1$ from which
$$\lambda(\xi)=|L|=\frac{|D|+1}2=\frac{d(\xi^2)+1}2$$
thus proving the assertion.